# How can I get the parameter name in java at run time

Tags: java, java-8

I am using Java 8. In Java 8 there is a method name as get parameter but it gives the output like `arg0`, `arg1`. However I want the exact parameter name. Can anybody tell me how to achieve it? I have seen some response like we can use paranamer. But I couldn't find the solution. I am trying to build an automation framework so I have this requirement.

for example if my function is

```
public void Login(String sUserName, String sPassword)
{
}
```

So in a different class file I want the output as  sUserName.

Comment: Unlike some languages, the parameters themselves are not named, they are just place holders for variables, which could be named anything in your code.  Java uses the parameter types to differentiate between different methods

Comment: How are you compiling the program? By default the compiler deletes parameter names.

Comment: can you show us what  you doing

Comment: I am running it through TestNG directly like run as -> TestNg Set

Comment: Eclipse -> project properties -> Java compiler -> Add variable attributes to generated class files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from Java 8, you can use Reflection API to retrieve parameters names:

```
Method someMethod = Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod");
Parameter[] parameters = someMethod.getParameters();
for(Parameter parameter : parameters)
{
    System.out.println(parameter.getName());
}
```

Also, see JavaDoc of [`Parameter#getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getName--):

> Returns the name of the parameter. If the parameter's name is present, then this method returns the name provided by the class file. Otherwise, this method synthesizes a name of the form argN, where N is the index of the parameter in the descriptor of the method which declares the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I already tried it and it gives me o/p like arg0, arg1. As I have two parameters in my function the it shows the first parameter as arg0 and 2nd as arg1 not the names as I have given in my function.

Comment: @shubhampandey Use the option `-parameters` when you compile the source code using `javac`, which `Stores formal parameter names of constructors and methods in the generated class file`.

Comment: How can I do it using Eclipse? As m running the code using TestNg framework in eclipse. Is there any setting in Eclipse for this?

Comment: @shubhampandey Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler, then check the option "Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)".

Comment: Still its givin same o/p: I am using following code:

for (Method method : CommonFunctions.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
      String name = method.getName(); 
      System.out.println("method is :"+name);
  Parameter[] param =   method.getParameters();
  for (Parameter parameter : param) {
   System.out.println("name of parameter is :" +parameter.getName());
  }

Comment: Hi I finally got the solution. Thanks a lotz for ur help :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Please add the information (about compiler options/eclipse options) to your answer instead of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support giving the variable names at run-time. (The variables's assigned "name" does not actually save when compiled.) 
One thing to try might be something along the lines of:

```
class NamedInteger{
    public String name;
    public Integer value;
}
```

Just worth a thought. Not sure if this would be what your wanting.

Comment: Did you happen to notice [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31129383/2055998)?

Answer (score 0):

Either you try

> Eclipse -> project properties -> Java compiler -> Add variable
>   attributes to generated class files.

Or compile your classes with debugging information as `javac -g:vars`

Above applies only for classes and not for interfaces.

If you absolutely must do this, there is an overkill that you can indulge yourself in. For that first, you must define proper java doc with parameter information in your class files.

```
/**
 * Print permutations of given string "aString".
 * @param fixed
 * @param aString
 */
```

Once this is done, you can use a bit of `Doclet` code to read documentation and get the parameter names from documentation.

```
 for (ClassDoc classDoc : root.classes()) {
   for (MethodDoc methodDoc : classDoc.methods()) {
     if (methodDoc.parameters() != null) {
       for (Parameter p : methodDoc.parameters()) {
         System.out.println(p.name());
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Well I am just suggesting a possibility; **Do not do this** because documentations can get really out dated real fast.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answers given by Eng.Fouad. You have to use jre 1.8, as the `getParameters` method is available in Java 8 only.

I've just used the following piece of code:

```
for (Method method: CommonFunctions.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    String name = method.getName();
    System.out.println("method is :" + name);
    Parameter[] param = method.getParameters();
    for (Parameter parameter: param) {
        System.out.println("name of parameter is :" + parameter.getName());
    }
}
```

Here, `CommonFunctions` can be replaced with the actual class whose methods' parameters' names must be read.

To enable it in Eclipse, you need to set up the following settings:

Window > Preference > Compiler > check option "Add Variable attribute to generated class file"(Usable through debugger)

Window Preference > Compiler > Store information about method parameters (Usable through reflection)