# Is it possible to get the name of variable passed to function in Java?

Tags: java, introspection

Sometimes I saw stack traces that said which value of which variable caused an exception to occur. So I guess it's possible to determine the name somehow. I've already searched, but haven't found anything suitable. Is this possible, and how?

What I am looking for:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int dogs = 2;
        int cats = 3;
        printAnimals(dogs);
        printAnimals(cats);
    }

    static void printAnimals(int animal) {
        System.out.println("User has " + animal + " " + ...(animal));
    }
}
```

Should print:

```
User has 2 dogs
User has 3 cats
```

**Edit:** [How can I get the parameter name in java at run time](/q/31129331) does not solve this. With

```java
static void printAnimals(int animal) throws Exception {
    Method thisMethod = Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("printAnimals", int.class);
    String species = thisMethod.getParameters()[0].getName();
    System.out.println("User has " + animal + " " + species);
}
```

prints:

```
User has 2 animal
User has 3 animal
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the parameter name in java at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129331/how-can-i-get-the-parameter-name-in-java-at-run-time)

Comment: @MrIrrelevant that would help if you need `animal`, not if you need `dogs` or `cats`

Comment: Regarding the name in the stacktraces: you mean that "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "a[2]" is null"? This was added to the native code of the JVM due to [JEP 358: Helpful NullPointerExceptions](https://openjdk.org/jeps/358). It is only applicable to NullPointerExceptions and it only resolves field names and possibly local variable names / parameter names. It cannot resolve the names of variables in the calling method.

Comment: It is also uncleary what such a hypothetical feature would resolve as variable name if you called your method as `printAnimals(42);`

Comment: I think there's unlikely a simple way for that, calls `printAnimals(dogs);` and `printAnimals(2);` are pretty much the same from `printAnimals` point of view: `2` somehow ends up in the call stack, and then the method makes use of it. Finding out how it got there would probably need disassembly of byte code preceding the call.

Comment: Local variable names are only available if debug information has been included in the class file. Besides that, @ThomasKläger already said everything.

Comment: @ThomasKläger maybe you may want to repost your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sometimes I saw stack traces that said which value of which variable caused an exception to occur.*

If by that you mean a message like

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "a[2]" is null

This was added to the JVM due to [JEP 358: Helpful NullPointerExceptions](https://openjdk.org/jeps/358). It is only applicable to NullPointerExceptions and it only resolves field names and possibly local variable names / parameter names (local names if the code is compiled with debug information, parameter names if it is compiled with debug information or parameter name information).

Even this code cannot resolve the names of variables in the calling method.

One problem with such a hypothetical feature that could resolve variable names in the calling method: what should it return as variable name if you call your method as

```
printAnimals(42);
```

Comment: It'd be interesting to see what abuse _is_ possible through this JEP though. Through some purposeful NPEs and parsing the error message, I wonder what (if any) information you can glean from the message that otherwise would be unavailable at the Java layer, short of decompiling the class files.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is usually done using a `Map` rather than individual variables. So instead of

```
    int dogs = 2;
    int cats = 3;
```

you would have:

```
    Map<String, Integer> animalNumbers = Map.of(
        "dogs", 2,
        "cats", 3
    );

    for (var entry : animalNumbers)
        printAnimals(entry);
```

...

```
static void printAnimals(Map.Entry<String, Integer> animal) {
    System.out.println("User has " + animal.getValue() + " " + animal.getKey());
}
```

You might also want something like:

```
Map<String, String> plurals = Map.of(
    "dog", "dogs",
    "cat", "cat",
    "mouse", "mice",
    "ox", "oxen"
);
```

and use it to select singular or plural according to the number of animals (this generally works in English but it's more complicated in other languages).

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, but my minimal example is only to clarify the functionality I want. The actual use case is in variable checking, like `isPositive("arg", arg)` which shall throw an IllegalArgumentException in case it is not, with a message like `'arg' -42 is not > 0` where I wondered whether I could dispose of the name string argument.

Comment: I see, in that case, as you've already learnt, it's not possible.